# Assinar XML Delphi "Classe não registrada"

Tags: delphi, xml

Estou tentando assinar um `XML` com o `Delphi`, a `TAG Signature`. Para isso estou usando rotinas já prontas que todas essas tem um ponto em comum.

```
**xmlDoc := CoDOMDocument50.Create;**
```

Durante a execução da erro do Windows "Classe não registrada". Consultando descobri que depende da `MSXML5`.

No site da Microsoft a instalação da `MSXML4` é completa e aparece instalado no Painel de Controle, porém se instalar a versão 5 ou 6, as DLLs são criadas, mas no painel de controle ainda mostra instalado a versão 4. Dando impressão que não é uma instalação completa. Já removi a versão 4 tentei instalar direto a 5 e a 6. Instaladores diferentes o erro persiste.

Aparentemente só falta isso para eu terminar o meu trabalho.

Obrigado.

Comment: Já tentou registrar as DLL manualmente? `regsvr32 "caminho\nome_dll"` ?

Comment: Resolvi baixando a DLL de outro site e registrando novamente. Aí aparece no Delphi para usar no "Import Type Library" que antes não aparecia. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi baixando a DLL de outro site e registrando novamente. Aí aparece no Delphi para usar no "Import Type Library" que antes não aparecia. Obrigado.